# Accessing IDs only in a Lazy Loaded Collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I know it is possible to access the id of a single object without actually loading the entity from the database.  Is it possible to access all the ids in a lazy loaded collection without initializing the actual collection?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think so. In the case of the single object, the ID of the referenced object is in a column in the table of the object owning the reference, so Hibernate can access it without an extra query. In the case of a OneToMany, the IDs are on a different table, so no matter what, Hibernate will have to trigger a new SELECT to fetch them (and with it, all the info about the object).